# How to schedule Jenkins to run based on Poll SCM and Periodically on same job?

Tags: jenkins, build-triggers

1. I want to configure the Jenkins in such a way that it should run based on Poll SCM(whenever there is a change) and also every Night Periodically (At 10:00).
   I want to set only one job for this task.is it possible?
2. Is it Possible to run Periodic build as CLEAN_BUILD and Poll SCM build Not as a CLEAN_BUILD (On same job).?

Comment: what version of jenkins are you using? on jenkins 2.7 at least the configure page has  check boxes for build triggers, so you can simply check both boxes

Comment: HI, Thank you  for the suggestion, I am able to run it with Poll as well as Periodically now. Is there any suggestion for Question 2 ?

Comment: since the periodic  build only runs at 10, you could have a build step that runs a shell script with something like (psuedo code) `if( <current timestamp> == 10 pm ){manually clean build}`

Comment: Thank you for your response @Austin_Anderson but i do not have a knowledge on Pseudo code. I am using the batch scripts which will be called from Jenkins based on poll SCM, do we get any environmental variable from Jenkins similar to <current timestamp>?